# How to set the default serializer in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm currently watching a video course about ASP.NET Web API. When a controller gets called, the data gets returned in JSON by **default**. I was just wondering, because when I copy this sample project from the video, I get XML.

The frustration is big, please help me to solve this.

I'm pretty new to ASP.NET Web API, so please bear with me.

**UPDATE**

The controller doesn't contain special code. It's the simple code, which gets generated from the **API Controller with empty read/write actions** template.

Comment: Could you add some code of your controller/action in question?

Comment: Could you show controller action that if frustrating you?

Comment: You can google a bit for `GlobalConfiguration` and `Formatters` :-)

Comment: What version of MVC are you using?

Comment: MVC 4, I updated my post

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ASP.NET WebAPI comes with built-in [content negotitation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kiranchalla/archive/2012/02/25/content-negotiation-in-asp-net-mvc4-web-api-beta-part-1.aspx) therefore the format of the return value is determined by the request itself - more specifically by the `Accept`/`Content-Type` headers (depending on which ones are present, `Accept` header appears to be favoured over the `Content-type`).

I assume you're viewing the results in a browser and by default it's probably asking for `application/xml`. You will need to toy around with some settings/developer tools on the browser and force it to send `Content-Type: application/json` to get the correct response (assuming your returning [HttpResponseMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.aspx)).

Comment: So whether XML or JSON gets returned is determined by the browser settings?

Comment: @ebeeb well not *quite*, it's determined by the **request** made by the browser - more specifically the `Content-Type` header. So based on which browser you are using you will get different results. You could probably toy with some developer tools on the one your using to force it to request a specific type.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong: it would be a bad manner if I determined the type of serialization on the application's side? Means forcing the application **not** to return XML.

Comment: @ebeeb not necessarily, if you want to specifically force your API to only return JSON then you can. However, it's usually a good idea to let the requesting application decide on which format it wants to work with (especially if you are getting the functionality for free).

Comment: I disagree with "Accept header appears to be favoured over the Content-type". 
Accept specifies result body format while Content-Type specifies request body format

Comment: @Ali it's not really up for debate, it's how it works (if the `Accept` header is missing the `Content-Type` is used to determine the return format).

Comment: @James try to add only content-type equal to text/xml, the response will be in json

Comment: @Ali I'm not in a position to do that, however, bare in mind this answer is 5 years old and was correct at the time of writing. If you read the linked article you can see it was tried & tested and that was the resultant behaviour.

Feel free to update the answer if you are finding that the default behaviour has now changed.

Answer (score 8):

in Global.asax: add the line:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
```

It'll look like this.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    BundleTable.Bundles.RegisterTemplateBundles();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

James is close, but the content negotiation actually uses the [Accept] header,
 not [Content-Type]

As with nearly everything else in MVC, you can override the content negotiation components to ensure the desire content is returned

W3c clearly states-

14.1 Accept

The Accept request-header field can be used to specify certain media types which are acceptable for the response.

-and-

14.17 Content-Type

The Content-Type entity-header field indicates the media type of the entity-body sent to the recipient or, in the case of the HEAD method, the media type that would have been sent had the request been a GET.

This page [headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) is very useful to understand request/response negotiation.

Comment: Actually it's both, it just depends on which headers are present, the `Accept` header does appear to get priority though. I updated my answer just for clarification.

Comment: Isn't it that the `Content-Type` specifies the content-type of the request you are sending and the `Accept` specifies what content-type you want to get as a response? I'm wondering if Web API might fall back to "guessing" your `Accept` by using your `Content-Type` where the accept is not provided by the caller?

Comment: I could see webAPI trying to infer the Accept value from the Content-Type.

I'd say its bad practice to omit Accept in a production application though, and I'd argue against an answer that both are acceptable/correct.

Updated my answer to back up this comment.

Comment: It needs to be stated that using Content-Type to request a return type is the wrong thing to do. The accepted answer should either be changed to my answer or be changed to reflect this. The accepted answer though it may technically 'work' with MS WebAPI, will likely not work with other stacks and more importantly does not follow the HTTP standard.

Comment: @bradodarb the question was specifically relating to the Web API and so the answer was targeted to that. However, this statement *"using Content-Type to request a return type is the wrong thing to do"* is misinformed. It's perfectly fine to do this, this is known as [Server-driven Negotiation](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec12.html#sec12.1) and *does* follow the HTTP standard.

Comment: From experience, on a GET request, the Accept header takes precedence (as we're telling the API what format we accept as a response) and for a POST request, the Content-Type header is required