# Content-Type - WebAPI - Request Header

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible for WEBAPI controller to return JSON, even if the header "Content-Type" is not present?

In the default setup, when the header is not present, Exception "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type ..." is raising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to your `WebApiConfig.cs`

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html") );
```

now you get json result unless when you send `text/xml` as "Content-Type"

Comment: Worked for me :) instead of text/html I was having problem with application/octet-stream

Answer (score 0):

generally web api can return both in xml format and json format, therefore while making a call to your web api you need to specify the content type in the header.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do so. Just change the default serializer to `Json Serializer`.  More details explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917795/how-to-set-the-default-serializer-in-asp-net-web-api).

Note: The default serializer of `WebApi` is `Json Serializer`. So, even if no content type headers are found on the request, you should get the response in `json` format.